# submitting a form in a dialog without postback with jquery/ajax/php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ok so I'm trying to submit address information without the page refreshing (or posting back). I keep getting an "unexpected end of input" and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. This is all new to me so sorry if there are noob mistakes!

**UPDATED** Updated PHP, see below. Still getting unexpected end of input error with the following changes.

jQuery code:

```
        $( "#ChangeAddressDialog" ).dialog({
            width:500,
            modal:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            buttons: [ 
                { text: "Ok", type: "submit", click: function() { 
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "classes/add-address.php",
                            timeout: 30000,
                            type: "POST",
                            data: $("#main_form").serialize(),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                alert("An error has occurred making the request. " + errorThrown);
                            },
                            success: function(data){
                                //do stuff here on success such as modal info
                                //$("#main_form").submit();
                                alert('Address change information has been successfully submitted.');
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                { text: "Close", click: function() { $(this).dialog( "close" ); } } ]
        });
    });
```

PHP code: **UPDATED**

```
<?php
require_once('../config.php');

$sqlCheck = ''; 
$parcel_id = isset($_POST['ParcelId']) ? $_POST['ParcelId'] : null;
$address1 = isset($_POST['Address1']) ? $_POST['Address1'] : null;
$address2 = isset($_POST['Address2']) ? $_POST['Address2'] : null;
$city = isset($_POST['City']) ? $_POST['City'] : null;
$state = isset($_POST['State']) ? $_POST['State'] : null;
$zip = isset($_POST['Zip']) ? $_POST['Zip'] : null;
$country = isset($_POST['Country']) ? $_POST['Country'] : null;

$db = new ezSQL_mysql(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO change_of_address (parcel_id, address_1, address_2, City, State, Zip, Country) VALUES ('" . $parcel_id . "','" . $address1 . "','" . $address2 . "','" . $city . "','" . $state . "','" . $zip . "','" . $country . "')");
if ($result == 1) {
    echo true;
} else {
    echo false;
}



?>
```

EDIT: For S.Pols

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#column-chooser').hide();
        $('#CommentsDialog').hide();
        $('#ChangeAddressDialog').hide();
        $('#HelpDialog').hide();
        $('#ExportDialog').hide();
        $("#SearchButton").click(function() { window.location.href = '/?s=' + $("#search").val(); });   
        $('#searchTable tr').click(function(){
            var parcel_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#ParcelId').val(parcel_id);
            $.ajax({
                url: "classes/get-apn.php?id=" + parcel_id,
                type: "GET",
                data: { parcel_id : parcel_id },
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown);
                },
                success: function(data){
                    //do stuff here on success
                    $('#ParcelNumber').html(data[0]["apn"]);
                    //$('#ViewComments').html('Veiw ' + count + ' Comments');
                }
            });
        });

    });//end document ready function

    /*$('#dataTable').DataTable({
        "searching": false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "scrollY": "300px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": false,
        "info": false
    });*/
    $( "#AddComment" )
        .button()
        .click(function( event ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#ShowColumnChooser').click(function() {
        //show/hide div
        $('#column-chooser').slideToggle('slow');
    });
    $('#Help').click(function() {
        //help dialog box
        $( "#HelpDialog" ).dialog({
            width: 500,
            modal:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            buttons: [ { text: "Close", click: function() { $(this).dialog( "close" ); } } ]
        });
    });
    $('#Export').click(function() {
        //export options dialog
        $( "#ExportDialog" ).dialog({
            width: 500,
            modal:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            buttons: [ { text: "Close", click: function() { $(this).dialog( "close" ); } } ]
        });
    });
    $('#ViewComments').click(function() {
        //view/add comments dialog
        $( "#CommentsDialog" ).dialog({
            height:300,
            width: 500,
            modal:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            buttons: [ { text: "Close", click: function() { $(this).dialog( "close" ); } } ]
        });
        $("#InsertComment").focus();
    });//end view comments click function

    $('#ChangeOfAddress').click(function() {
        //change of address dialog
        $('#change_of_address_form').val('1');
        $( "#ChangeAddressDialog" ).dialog({
            width:500,
            modal:true,
            closeOnEscape:true,
            buttons: [ 
                { text: "Ok", type: "submit", click: function() { 
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "classes/add-address.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: $("#main_form").serialize(),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            error: function(SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                                alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown)
                            },
                            success: function(result){
                                //do stuff here on success such as modal info
                                $("#main_form").submit();
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        })
                    } 
                },
                { text: "Close", click: function() { $(this).dialog( "close" ); } } ]
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $('#datepicker1,#datepicker2,#datepicker3,#datepicker4').datepicker({
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonImage: 'images/calendar.png',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonText: 'Select Date'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know how your dialog is implemented but aren't you missing a `return false` at the end of your submit function to prevent the default form behavior.

Comment: "unexpected end of input" means you forgot to close a tag. I don't think it's this code which causes the error. Can you post the rest of your PHP code?

Comment: @S.Pols that is all my php code. just inputs the user information into the database. doesn't do anything else besides that.

Comment: Ok i'm sorry i thought it was a PHP script. Can you post the javascript above and/or beyond your current jQuery code?

Comment: see above. too long to post here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not echoing content from your php script.

```
$result = $db->query( ... );
```

I'm not familiar with ezSQL_mysql but it should be returning an object or an array, you should then echo it, something like:

```
if ($result){
    echo 'true'; // or 1, or '{"success': 'ok'}
}else{
    echo 'false'; // or 0, or '"success': 'error'}
}
```

or

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);  // if $result is an associative array
```

Try calling the php script from your browser and play with the responses that better suit your needs. Given that you will be using the response in javascript, json responses are the best you can use. Be sure to tell php to output the response as json instead of text using `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

In the js side you can use console.log in both functions to see what the server is returning

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Is anything returned on an insert statement?

Comment: I haven't used ezSQL lib but you can try doing a var_dump($result); to see what is returned. :)

Comment: I found out that it returns a boolean value. So I added the if else statement with the true false as strings and as not and neither worked. I still get "unexpected end of input error" :(

Comment: Your ajax is expecting a json reponse, as such it is expecting it to be formatted correctly. Try changing dataType: 'json', in your ajax call to dataType: 'text', . Also if you plan on using a text response change header('Content-Type: application/json'); to header('Content-Type: text/plain'); on the php side. Keep in mind that echoing false, instead of 'false' from php will print nothing. Once you have this working it's worth it to play with the responses and implement a full json response which is much more flexible and robust. Let us know if this works!